# Given Parent Array and Values Array. Find Best Possible Sum in a tree

Tags: data-structures, tree

Given Parent Array Such that parent[i]=j where j is the parent and Value array . Need to Find Best possible sum.

Root node will have -1 as parent.

Best Possible sum is maximum sum in one of the tree paths.

Ex)

```
 Integer[] parent = new Integer[] { -1, 0, 0, 2, 3 };
 Integer[] values = new Integer[] { 0, 4, 6, -11, 3 };

     (0/0)----(1/4)
     |
     |
     (2/6)
     |
     |
     (3/-11)
     |
     |
     (4/3)
```

Maximum sum here would be  6+0+4=10 for path 2-->0-->1.

I have tried solving it the dfs way. But not sure if it works for all cases. Below is my code. It gives all possible sum. we can take out max from that.

```
    package com.programs.algo;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;

    public class BestPossibleSum {

        static class Node<T> {

        T label;
        T data;
        List<Node<T>> nodes;
       }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Integer[] parent = new Integer[] { -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 5 };
    Integer[] values = new Integer[] { 0, 4, 6, -11, 3, 10, 11 };

    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(parent));
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(values));
    bestPossibleSum(list1, list2);
}

static List<Node<Integer>> tree = new ArrayList<>();

private static void bestPossibleSum(List<Integer> list1, List<Integer> list2) {
    int adj[][] = new int[list1.size()][list1.size()];
    createTree(list1, list2, adj);
    List<Integer> traversedNodes = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> sumOfraversedNodes = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < adj.length; i++) {
        dfs(tree.get(i), traversedNodes, sumOfraversedNodes);
        traversedNodes.clear();
    }

    System.out.println(sumOfraversedNodes);
}

private static void dfs(Node<Integer> tree, List<Integer> traversedNodes, List<Integer> sums) {
    if (!traversedNodes.contains(tree.label)) {
        traversedNodes.add(tree.label);
        sums.add(getSum(traversedNodes));
        for (Node<Integer> child : tree.nodes) {
            dfs(child, traversedNodes, sums);
        }
    }
}

private static Integer getSum(List<Integer> traversedNodes) {
    System.out.println(traversedNodes);
    return traversedNodes.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);
}

private static void createTree(List<Integer> parent, List<Integer> values, int[][] adj) {

    for (int i = 0; i < parent.size(); i++) {
        Node<Integer> node = new Node<>();
        node.label = i;
        node.data = values.get(i);
        node.nodes = new ArrayList<>();
        tree.add(i, node);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < parent.size(); i++) {
        if (parent.get(i) != -1) {
            adj[parent.get(i)][i] = 1;
            adj[i][parent.get(i)] = 1;
            tree.get(parent.get(i)).nodes.add(tree.get(i));
        }
    }

    tree.forEach(t -> {
        System.out.println(t.label);
        System.out.println(t.nodes.stream().map(m -> m.label).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    });
    // System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(adj));
}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried? did you transfer your data to tree-based data structure? I would recommend after moving to tree to traverse the tree in-order (DFS would work) and break all sub tree that have negative values

Comment: Does it has to be binary tree? Can it the path have a star shape? (for non-binary tree)

Comment: have posted my code which i have tried.  not sure if that works for all cases. Have not used binary tree in the solution i have tried.

Comment: Did my post helped you?

Comment: yes it surely did. I have posted java code for the same considering it to be a binary tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would divide your question to 2 different issues:

1. Build tree from your data
2. Find the max sum

I wrote the code in `PHP` but you can convert it to any language you need (my `JAVA` skill are bit rusty...)

**Build the Tree**:

```
$parent = array( -1, 0, 0, 2, 3 );
$values = array(0, 4, 6, -11, 3 );

function getNode($id, $data) {
    return array("id" => $id, "data" => $data, "childs" => array());
}
function addToTree($node, &$root, $parentsId) {
    if ($parentsId == -1)
        $root = $node;
    else if ( $root["id"] == $parentsId)
        $root["childs"][] = $node;
    else
        foreach($root["childs"] as &$child)
            addToTree($node, $child, $parentsId);
}

$root = null;
for($i = 0; $i < count($parent); $i++) {
    addToTree(getNode($i, $values[$i]), $root, $parent[$i]);
}
```

Now `root` if contain you "tree-like" data. Notice this code works only if the nodes given at the right order and it cannot support multi root (assume tree and not forest)

**Find max path**:

```
function maxPath($node) {
    $sum = $node["data"];
    foreach($node["childs"] as $child) {
        $s = maxPath($child);
        if ($s > 0) // if its not positive then don't take it
            $sum += $s;
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

This recursive function will get your max-sum-path. Notice this will allow multi-child per node and also the path can have star-shape.

Answer (score 0):

Posting Java code considering it as tree with left and right nodes.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-a-binary-tree-from-parent-array-representation/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-maximum-path-sum-in-a-binary-tree/

```
  private static int maxSum(Node<Integer> btree, Result result) {

    if (btree == null)
        return 0;
    int l = maxSum(btree.left, result);
    int r = maxSum(btree.right, result);

    System.out.println(l + " " + r + " " + btree.data);
    int maxSingle = Math.max(Math.max(l, r) + btree.label, btree.label);
    int maxTop = Math.max(l + r + btree.label, maxSingle);

    result.val = Math.max(maxTop, result.val);
    return maxSingle;
}

private static Node<Integer> createBinaryTree(Integer[] parent, Node<Integer> root) {
    Map<Integer, Node<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
        map.put(i, new Node<>(i));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
        if (parent[i] == -1) {
            root = map.get(i);
        } else {
            Node<Integer> par = map.get(parent[i]);
            Node<Integer> child = map.get(i);
            if (par.left == null) {
                par.left = child;
            } else {
                par.right = child;
            }
        }
    }

    return root;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 . convert the given parent array into graph with the following steps :
unordered_map<int,vector<pair<int,int>>> graph;

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(parents[i]!=-1){
    graph[parents[i]].push_back({i,values[i]});
    graph[i].push_back({parents[i],values[parents[i]]});
    }
}
```

2.apply DFS on each node and check the maximum Path Sum

```
vector<bool> vis(n,false);
int res=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    vis.clear();
    dfs(i,vis,mp,values,res);
}
```

3. DFS function

void dfs(int src,vector&vis,unordered_map<int,

```
vector<pair<int,int>>>&graph,vector<int>&values,int res){
res+=values[src];
ans=max(ans,res);
vis[src]=true;

for(int i=0;i<graph[src].size();i++){
    if(!vis[graph[src][i].first]){
        dfs(graph[src][i].first,vis,graph,values,res);
    }
}
vis[src]=false;
}
```

> > > > > > 

**C++ code :**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>  
using namespace std;

int ans=INT_MIN;

void dfs(int src,vector<bool>&vis,unordered_map<int,
vector<pair<int,int>>>&graph,vector<int>&values,int res){
res+=values[src];
ans=max(ans,res);
vis[src]=true;

for(int i=0;i<graph[src].size();i++){
    if(!vis[graph[src][i].first]){
        dfs(graph[src][i].first,vis,graph,values,res);
    }
}

vis[src]=false;
}

int maxPathSum(vector<int>&parents,vector<int>&values){
int n=parents.size();
unordered_map<int,vector<pair<int,int>>> mp;

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(parents[i]!=-1){
    mp[parents[i]].push_back({i,values[i]});
    mp[i].push_back({parents[i],values[parents[i]]});
    }
}

vector<bool> vis(n,false);
int res=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    vis.clear();
    dfs(i,vis,mp,values,res);
}

return ans;
}

int main(){
vector<int> parent = {-1,0,0,2,3};    //{-1,0,1,2,0};
vector<int> values = {0,4,6,-11,3};   //{-2,10,10,-3,10};
cout<<maxPathSum(parent,values)<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I got this problem in One of the company's hackerrank test.
Here is my solution. All test cases have been passed successfully

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;


class Result {

    /*
     * Complete the 'bestSumDownwardTreePath' function below.
     *
     * The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
     * The function accepts following parameters:
     *  1. INTEGER_ARRAY parent
     *  2. INTEGER_ARRAY values
     */
     
     static int bestPath = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    public static int bestSumDownwardTreePath(List<Integer> parent, List<Integer> values) {
        
        if(parent.size() == 1) return values.get(0);
        
        
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> tree = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 1; i < parent.size(); i++) {
            List<Integer> temp = tree.getOrDefault(parent.get(i), null);
            if(temp == null) {
                temp = new ArrayList<>();
                temp.add(i);
                tree.put(parent.get(i), temp);
            }
            
            else {
                temp.add(i);
            }
        }
        
        findBestSum(parent, values, tree, 0, 0);
        
        return bestPath;

    }
    
    public static void findBestSum(List<Integer> parent, List<Integer> values, 
                            Map<Integer, List<Integer>> tree, int root, int sum) {
                                
        
        
        sum = sum + values.get(root);
        bestPath = Math.max(bestPath, sum);
        sum = Math.max(0, sum);
        
        if(tree.get(root) == null) return;
        
        for(Integer child: tree.get(root)) {
            findBestSum(parent, values, tree, child, sum);
        }
        
    }

}
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

        int parentCount = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());

        List<Integer> parent = IntStream.range(0, parentCount).mapToObj(i -> {
            try {
                return bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        })
            .map(String::trim)
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            .collect(toList());

        int valuesCount = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());

        List<Integer> values = IntStream.range(0, valuesCount).mapToObj(i -> {
            try {
                return bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        })
            .map(String::trim)
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            .collect(toList());

        int result = Result.bestSumDownwardTreePath(parent, values);

        bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
        bufferedWriter.newLine();

        bufferedReader.close();
        bufferedWriter.close();
    }
}
```